# how to change the date format in excel to text so it can convert in mysql

Tags: mysql, database, excel, date

I have data in excel in which there is a column date formatted dd/mm/yyyy.
that excel data I want to convertted to mysql.
the problem is after converting this, mysql read as 0000-00-00.

I used formula **=TEXT(A1,"YYYY-MM-DD")** but the excel ask for punctuation mark (') in front of sign equal to (=)
I change the date to 'YYYY-MM-DD and mysql success to read the date.

What exactly the best formula I used to apply to all (if more than 200) date so it can read by mysql.

thanks

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

1. Highlight the column
2. Right click and select **Format Cells**
3. Select **Custom**
4. In the **Type** field enter yyyy-mm-dd

Now your dates should be in the correct format.

Comment: It still not changed.. i tried again and again.. it should using format like '1990-01-01 but how it applies fast for more than hundred date inside the excel i still don't get it..

Comment: Strange. That should do the trick. Is it working for some cells but not all or is it not working at all?